# Can I Associate an Apps Script with or Deploy an Apps Script to Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have some scripts which make copies of files and folders in Google Drive so users won't have to do this manually, but at the moment these scripts are just script files sitting in the drive and users need to open and run the script. I don't want the users to have to click Run > Run Function, and see the code, etc, so I'm looking for a better way to deploy these.

Ideally, the scripts would appear in a dropdown menu when the users went to their Drive. Is there a way to do this?

I'm considering just creating a Doc. Then users will have to open the doc whenever they want to run one of the scripts, but at least they won't see all the guts. I'm new to Apps script, so I might be overlooking an obvious, better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script doesn't have a way to add UI elements to Google Drive web UI.

I think that this could be achieved by creating a Chrome Extension but I didn't tried this yet.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs